# ¿Como actualizar una base de datos en base a un DataGridView en VB.net?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, vb.net, datagrid, dataset

Estoy cargando un dataset directo a un DataGridView, este tiene la opción de editar sus registros (En el DataGridView), pero al terminar da la opción de guardar los cambios, mi duda es como guardar solo aquellos que fueron modificados directo a la base de datos de una manera rápida, ya que recorrer todo y comparar seria mas lento (por la cantidad de información)

Comment: Considero que puedes utilizar un evento de validating o CellValueChanged que regularmente se activa al momento que la celda pierde el focus. En ese evento puedes capturar el row en el que se hicieron cambios. Se ejecutaría cada vez que haces un cambio en el grid. Es un WindowsForm o utilizas otra librería?

Comment: si es un WindowsForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta manera podrías hacerlo en el evento CellValueChanged, el cual se ejecutaría cuando cambies un valor en la celda. Este nuevo valor lo envías a un método de actualización. Asimismo con e.RowIndex y e.ColumnIndex obtienes los demás indices para validaciones.

```
Private Sub Grid_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles Grid.CellValueChanged
Try
 If Grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   Dim nuevoValorCelda As Integer = CInt(Grid.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value)
     metodoActualizacion(nuevoValorCelda)
 End If
Catch ex As Exception
 Throw
End Catch
End Sub
```

Comment: Antes que todo, Gracias por la idea, pero el problema es que la idea principal de esa ventana es editar productos, entonces esta ventana cuenta con un botón de "Grabar" el cual graba todo(obviamente) al terminar de editar dicha lista, pero también en un registro el usuario puede editar mas de una columna... entonces conforme a tu código, seria factible grabar dichas columnas en un array y al finar recorrerlo para grabar?

Comment: Recorrer ese array sería casi lo mismo que recorrer el grid pero lo puedes hacer.  Las desventajas de usar un botón para guardar al final los cambios, es que pueda suceder algún error y si de una lista de 100 productos, actualizó 50 perdería todo ese trabajo para volver a comenzar, o si por accidente cierra la pantalla pierde todo. Al usar el evento como  te dije, es cambio hecho cambio grabado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya solucione ese problema, con tu ayuda